# как в Netbeans посмотреть число с плавающей точкой в двоичном формате?

Tags: java, netbeans

как в Netbeans посмотреть число с плавающей точкой в двоичном формате? Например: есть число float 12.34f. В двоичном  виде оно будет выглядеть - 10001010111000010100100. Как я могу в двоичном виде увидеть это на консоли? Благодарю.

Comment: Да не, не так оно в двоичном виде выглядит.

Comment: Double.toLongBits()